# SQL to XML Nested Output Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have an issue with the formatting when outputting SQL to XML.

The following works as expected:-

```
SELECT 
   AC.ACCOUNT AS 'Acct',
   (SELECT ITEMNO AS 'ITEM' 
   FROM ITEMS AS ITEMS1 WITH(NOEXPAND) 
   WHERE ITEMS1.CODE = AC.CODE
   FOR XML PATH ('Items'), TYPE)
FROM 
   AC WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
   ITEMS ON AC.CODE = ITEMS.CODE
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('Accts'), ELEMENTS
```

Which outputs the following XML:

```
<Accts>
   <Acct>94615130</Acct>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>1001</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>1050</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>1051</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>1054</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>1055</ITEM>
   </Items>
   ....
</Accts>
```

But when I add an extra clause in the where of the subquery like this:

```
     SELECT 
     AC.ACCOUNT AS 'Acct',
     (SELECT ITEMNO AS 'ITEM' 
     FROM ITEMS AS ITEMS1 WITH(NOEXPAND) 
     WHERE ITEMS1.CODE = AC.CODE
     AND ITEMS1.ITEMNO = ITEMS.ITEMNO
     FOR XML PATH ('Items'), TYPE)
FROM 
     AC WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN 
     ITEMS ON AC.CODE = ITEMS.CODE
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('Accts'), ELEMENTS
```

I get this xml output:

```
<Accts>
   <Acct>94615130</Acct>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>28</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Acct>94615130</Acct>
   <Items>
       <ITEM>36</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Acct>94615130</Acct>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>114</ITEM>
   </Items>
   <Acct>94615130</Acct>
   <Items>
      <ITEM>161</ITEM>
   </Items>
   ....
</Accts>
```

which is not what I want. I need all items to be grouped under the account number like in the first example rather than repeating the account number for every item.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of the inner join in your outer query. ie:

```
SELECT 
   AC.ACCOUNT AS 'Acct',
   (SELECT ITEMNO AS 'ITEM' 
   FROM ITEMS AS ITEMS1 
   WHERE ITEMS1.CODE = AC.CODE
   FOR XML PATH ('Items'), TYPE)
FROM 
   AC 
FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('Accts'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason for the join is so I can match Code and ItemNo in the where clause of the subquery as matching by Code only is not unique enough.

Comment: @user1319501 But that's covered in the inner XML, no?

Comment: @user1319501 The `select .. as Item` xml

Comment: I need the where clause to be like this:- WHERE ITEMS1.CODE = AC.CODE AND ITEMS1.ITEMNO = ITEMS.ITEMNO, that's why I had the inner join in the outer query. Adding this extra clause in the where however repeats the account number for every item number in the xml